# Set point NOT IN CENTER of polygon

Tags: algorithm

I have a free shaped polygon. Now I draw a smaller polygon inside with a same form i.e buffer zone with negative width. Then put a point with in my buffer zone center. Its looks like this:

[image]

OK. But now I add a buffer zone with positive width and put a point in centre. I get:

[image]

You see that one point lies on another point. Its no good I want to see both points.

Sure I can just move a point from centre away but if I do I will have a polygon with strange shape that can go beyond the boundaries.

Can you give an advice what to do?

Comment: Would you be able to have another try at explaining your Question - I think it is about how to display overlapping features but am reluctant to try and advise when I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: No idea how to implement algorithm but see postgis manual : http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Centroid.html , ST_centroid , st_pointonsurface, st_point_on_circle. Those may give you more idea what you want. pointonsurface implementation (see postgis source/libwgeom source) could be what you are looking for

Comment: You can use an offset for the display of your points, provided that they are placed in approximately the same way in all features (this might be a stretch though). In Arcmap there's such a functionality for point properties, and I assume there's something similar in Qgis.

Comment: If you just want an exclusion zone, you can buffer the preferred label, then difference that out of the second polygon, so the resulting centroid wouldn't overlap.

Comment: Guys sorry for bad question explanation that couse my english is terrible.

Comment: More info! What applications are you using? Are you interested in displaying a label at the centroids of polygons, or *creating points* at the centroids of polygons and labelling them?

Comment: I need to create points. Labels created automatically. I work with russian gis InGeo and c#, so solution will not easy. Now i have a two options 1 - straight skeleton 2 - take a two random polygon's vertex and create bisectors for then. And create point with label in  intersection point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for complex shapes could be to create the [straight skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) of your polygons and place your two points at two different locations on these lines (e.g. 25 and 75 % of the longest line). For most shapes you can also use the medial axis or its approximation (e.g. straight skeleton lines that do not touch any edges of your polygon), but this would not work for circles and regular polygons (the "axis" is then a point).

Another solution is to split your polygons in 2 (example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53952/splitting-large-polygons?rq=1)) then place one point in the first part and the second point in the second part.

Note that Vince's solution seems quite robust too. A variant is to place two random points in each inside buffered polygon with a minimum allowed distance to avoid "overlaps"