# Accuracy problems with 'Feature To Polygon' in ArcGIS 10.7?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, splitting

I have a question regarding the accuracy of `Feature to Polygon` in ArcGIS 10.7. My data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT?usp=sharing).

I have a glacier shapefile and a polyline. I want to split the glacier using the line feature with `Feature to Polygon`. I get no error messages, however, the results seems a bit off as the cut appears more than 100m away from the actual line. I have repeated this with several other lines, using the GUI as well as `arcpy` - the error stays the same.

What am I missing?

Does this have something to do with the projection?

Both objects are in the same projected coordinate system (WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N).

EDIT:
I'm trying to do this in Python. I have access to the Advanced License, so I've tried [CutPolygonByLines](https://github.com/tforward/CutPolygonByLines), but the code gives me errors. [SplitPolygonsWithLines](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431) works, but only as a toolbox as the code provided is pretty unreadable.

[image: example]

Comment: I'm curious are you trying to split a polygon with the line, or are you trying to build polygons using the glacier lines and the "splitting" line to create two polygons?  If the latter what units is your tolerance set to in the Feature to Polygon tool?

Comment: I am just trying to split the polygon with the line - but it sounds as if there is a better way? Do you have any suggestions?
(Btw: the tolerance is set to the default of 0.001 meters)

Comment: The Feature to Polygon tool requires an Advanced License so how are you creating polygons?  If you only have a few splits to make the easiest things to do is use the cut polygons tool and trace the lines.  Programmatically you could look at this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124198/optimizing-arcpy-code-to-cut-polygon?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by "how am I creating polygons". I can use `Feature To Polygon`, so I guess I must have the Advanced License (my IT Dept took care of those things for me^^). 
Thanks a lot for the link, that does look promising! I just have to make one split per polygon. 

However, it still seems strange that the `Feature to Polygon` tool is so inaccurate, doesn't it?