# Alternative to XTools' Split Polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geoprocessing, line

I have a model in ArcGIS 10.3.1 which splits a large (> 1,000) polygons by a road network (as polylines). Currently, I am using Xtools' Split Polygons, but this would require an end-user to have a copy of XTools which I need to not be a requirement. I have found [this](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431) tool, but, when I have tried to use it, it takes a very long time to run (much longer than the XTools equivalent). Does anyone know of any other tools which do the same thing, but are not locked behind non-ArcGIS purchasing licenses and are ideally only using ArcGIS geoprocessing tools?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31965/automated-geoprocesing-tool-to-slice-clip-or-cut-polygons-using-polylines-usin

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/programatically-splitting-polygon-with-line

Comment: @Midavalo, first link has Dalton's answer as best which I've already referenced above as the tool that takes too long. Second link has ET Wizards as the best answer which, without a license, has a max feature count of 300.

Comment: have you looked at the suggestion on how to possibly speed up Dalton's tool?

Comment: @Midavalo I do not see the comment you're referring to. Which thread and post? I see a Python script by user John, but that's the only thing I see that could be faster.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say in the link you mentioned in your question it offers a suggestion to speed it up by limiting "how far the lines will attempt to extend"

Comment: how long is "a very long time"?  sometimes this is the trade-off for using provided tools instead of specific third party tools

Comment: @Midavalo, I do not think I implemented that limit, but I seem to have forgotten to write the answer to that in my notes. By a "very long time" I mean on the order of three hours for maybe 10,000 features. I think the result that helped point me to will work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any extra info rather than as comments.  Please also include how long it runs using XTools for comparison.

Comment: @Midavalo extra information being the rough time it takes? I'll post the answer just as soon as they stop trying to shut down my place of work... might take a bit.

Comment: comments are intended for potential answerers to request additional information or clarification.  Your response to those comments should be as [edit]s to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "Feature to Polygon", advanced license required? This tool will Cut Polygons with a Polyline FC. If you don't want the Road Network creating new polygons, first Clip the Road Network by Polygons so you are only dividing or cutting the existing Polygons.

Comment: Funny, I was just reading your response on a post referenced by @Midavalo. Anyways, this set me down the right path, I think.

I took your idea of clipping the transit routes to the polygons of interest; however, when I ran the Feature to Polygon tool some of my polygons were so tortured that it was really hard to find a clear way of extracting the features I wanted. So, I simply buffered the clipped routes by 1 meter then used the erase tool. I can't believe I didn't think of this before. I'd like to not remove that much of the polygon, but it should be fine.

Comment: Mark as solved it @klewis suggestion helped