# Is there an alternate tool for ''Split Polygons with Lines" tool in ArcGIS.10v?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, splitting

I wanted to use Split Polygons with Lines tool in ArcGIS.10v. We don't have ArcInfo license. Is there an alternate tool which serves similar solution?

[image: Example image]

Comment: Have you tried one from advanced editing toolbar?

Comment: Are you asking about a Geoprocessing or Editing tool?  You say that you do not have an "ArcInfo" license but that is the old name for the current Advanced level license.  What version are you using and at what license level?  There may be no point in us providing an ArcGIS 10.5 solution using a Standard level license if you are using ArcGIS 9.1 at an ArcView license level.

Comment: @PolyGeo Please try to not put on hold the questions asked. You may not understand the question but the answer seekers think they made a query clearly. Instead you could ask for clarity.

Comment: I understand that you may be seeking an answer to one of two questions i.e. seeking a Geoprocessing tool or seeking an editing function.  The onus is on you as its asker to make which it is clear by using the [edit] button beneath your question before more people answer what is potentially a question other than that which you are asking.  My comment already asks you to clarify and it is placed on hold purely to prevent more potentially unrelated (or only loosely related) answers being placed on it until you have.

Comment: In any event this may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/programatically-splitting-polygon-with-line

Comment: If you wish to include a picture please use the Picture button which enables you to browse to an on disk image.

Answer (score 1):

When requesting alternative tools in ArcMap you should always go to http://codesharing.arcgis.com/ first where there are many user community contributed tools. You are *never* the first person who has this problem and in many cases someone has created a similar tool. Have a look at the [Cut Polygons Without Selection](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7b85e55be2ab46318cc8a7089f168718) tool, sounds like what you need, although it appears it is for 10.1 and higher and the tool description does not state what license level you need.