# Dividing area into polygons from road network using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I'm trying to divide a closed boundary into sub zones. These sub zones will be of shapes based on a road network. I have tried split tool but it is not working for this.

What tool should I use?

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: By not working, I meant that I'm split isn't the right tool for this. Or I don't know the use of split for this purpose

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible with standard functionality, but please see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31965/automated-geoprocesing-tool-to-slice-clip-or-cut-polygons-using-polylines-usin or here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/splitting-polygon-with-line-using-arcpy

Comment: Features to polygon will do it. You can select parts belonging to original polygons after.

Comment: the two references were  helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the polygon into polyline
2. Merge the Polyline with road network
3. Convert the merged feature class back into polygon

This would create sub-polygons for all you area that has been intersected with you boundary.

However this may have some problems in the corners where the roads do not intersect the border.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked and it was really easy for me to implement.